# Could not parse LLM output

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",temperature=0.3)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history",return_messages=True)
agent_chain = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True, memory=memory)

human_message = "hi"

while(True):
  bot_message = agent_chain.run(input=human_message);
  print(">>>>> Assist: ", bot_message)
  print(">>>>> Human:", end=" ")
  human_message = input();
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\app.py", line 48, in bot_message =
> agent_chain.run(input=human_message);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py",
> line 492, in run return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags,
> metadata=metadata)[
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py",
> line 292, in call raise e File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py",
> line 286, in call self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager) File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py",
> line 1122, in _call next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py",
> line 930, in _take_next_step raise e File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py",
> line 919, in _take_next_step output = self.agent.plan(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py",
> line 532, in plan return self.output_parser.parse(full_output)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "D:\work\gpt\booking_bot\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\conversational_chat\output_parser.py",
> line 50, in parse raise OutputParserException(f"Could not parse LLM
> output: {text}") from e
> langchain.schema.output_parser.OutputParserException: Could not parse
> LLM output: Hello! How can I assist you today?

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working in my system:

[image]

```
Name: langchain
Version: 0.0.281
```

you may follow [Handle parsing errors](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/how_to/handle_parsing_errors)
 docs

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Have you kept continue chatting on that code and aren't there any errors without handle_parsing_errors? My langchain version is 0.0.288

Comment: I could make it work without exception while "Could not parse LLM output:" error comes out, following your recommendation. but I don't like the message "Could not parse LLM output" since this is because it cannot reason action type from the next chat.

Comment: @WilliamHarris did you follow the link that i provided